# A sequence on $\{x_n\} \subset (0,1)$ such that $\lim_{n \to \infty} x_n=1$ with nice minimum distance properties.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

I am looking for a nice example of sequence $\{x_n\} \subset (0,1)$ such that

1. $\lim_{n \to \infty} x_n=1$.
2. $|x_n-x_k|= f(|n-k|)$ for some explicit function $f$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your conditions are impossible to fulfill. Suppose you had such a sequence $x_n$ and function $f$. Then for any $n$
$$f(|n-(n-1)|)=f(1)$$

is constant. But we also know

$$ \lim_{n\to\infty}|x_n-x_{n-1}|=0$$

The only way we can have a constant distance between consecutive terms in a converging sequence is if the sequence is constant. But $x_n$ converges to $1$ which implies $x_n=1$, a contradiction to the fact that $x_n\in (0,1)$.

Comment: Thanks. You are correct.  My goal was to find a  nice sequence where we have $|x_n-x_k|$ for all $k, n$.  I didn't' ask the question right, but this my fault. I will count your answer.